# MongoDb query with alike criteria gives an error

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

Here is code;

```
Order order = new Order();
order.setPaymentType("1");
Query query = new Query(new Criteria().alike(Example.of(order)));
mongoTemplate.find(query, Order.class);
```

and it returns nothing. (there are lots of order with paymentType=1)
When I try to change query like this;

```
Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("paymentType").alike(Example.of("1")));
```

it gives an error;

```
MongoPersistentEntity must not be null!
```

Comment: `new Criteria().alike(Example.of(order))` should work.